# WAN Miniport (Network Monitor) #2 network adapter has exclamation mark in device manager

Tags: networking, drivers, device-manager, network-monitoring

I have `WAN Miniport (Network Monitor) #2` network adapter with exclamation mark in device manager.

[image]

Description says

> This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the
>   drivers required for this device. (Code 31)

The `Uninstall` button does nothing.

How to fix/uninstall?

Comment: What model of PC and Windows version do you have this problem on? I've had this problem on a Thinkpad T430 running Windows 8 and it has been an ongoing problem for months. Lenovo forums are packed with people with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right-click on the WAN Miniport, select `“Update Driver”`.

Then select `“Browse my computer”`, Followed by `“Let me pick driver from a list”`.

Un-check `“Show compatible hardware”`. From the Manufacturer list, choose Microsoft, and from the Network Adapter list, choose “MAC Bridge Miniport”. (Choose any device. If un-sure, just select the first entry, which should be the: `Generic Broadband device driver`.

Back in the device manager, delete the `“MAC Bridge Miniport”` device.

Once you're done deleting the device, you MUST reboot your PC.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. Btw after reboot I lost network connection at all...

Comment: You lost connection? How did you sort it? Did you connect automatically or have to go into device manager again? Does 'Wan Miniport' show for you now or no?

Comment: Yes, connection was lost totally. I have D-Link router with DHCP, but main adapter was marked not connected in diagnostics. Never seen that before (not cable not connected or something common). I was to remove main network adapter entry, and also that Microsoft's with debug, and even after that I was not seeing network for some time. Now it went back and no WAN adapter anymore.